# Table representation of different kind and connection of multicast machine

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wandering what is the best way to organize the following into a relational DB structure (specifically an Oracle db).

I have to represent many hosts; every host is streaming (multicasting, input is with and without source filtering) one or more streams which contain an unknown number of components.

There are many kind of machines that will apply different kinds of modification based on some specific configuration (that have to be stored), and almost all kind of combination is valid. Normally based on that info, a machine will take some component, eventually change it in some way and restream it; others will just reorganize multiple multicast components (so they have multiple IP addresses).

My user will probably be looking for information about a specific host or component, but many views will have to be provided, which will navigate the data in every "relation direction".

I've camed up with a lot of ideas, like creating a standard "host" table, that has 2 fields, containing the specialized table name and row (obviously all specialized tables are a lot different from each other). But this clashes with the foreign keys perspective (only one parent table defined on table creation); so maybe it is a better idea to make specialized tables point to host table with foreign key, but then that relation has be "reverse navigable" (possible, but I feel like it is a hack).

Also for multicast I've come up with two alternatives, as it is a many-to-many relationship, it will use a third connection table, but the problem is *what* to put in that table to keep it aligned when one multicast or machine IP changes.

I'm really lost in that as I can't even find some good keyword to point me to some example or discussion about an organization with such complexity.